# Fetch image from library and scan through QR code

Tags: iphone, qr-code, zbar-sdk

I am using QR code sdk to scan for QR codes, but problem is that it is working on camera not on simulator. I tried a lot over the net but doesn't find any perfect working solution. Can anyone guide me for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to fetch image from photo library, by default app opens camera and captures image and then scans to get its codes, and i want it to use library rather than camera. But i am unable to do so yet, that's why looking for some help.

Answer (score 1):

**Create the reader.**

This is as simple as creating a new ZBarReaderController:

> ZBarReaderController *reader = [ZBarReaderController new];

**Setup a delegate to receive the results.**

The delegate should implement the ZBarReaderDelegate protocol, which inherits from UIImagePickerControllerDelegate:

> reader.readerDelegate = self;

**Configure the reader.**

You will need to set the sourceType appropriately. Aside from the properties of the reader itself, you can configure the decoder via the scanner property:

> if([ZBarReaderController isSourceTypeAvailable:
>                                UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
>       reader.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera; [reader.scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
>                   config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
>                   to: 0];

Follow these [steps](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/picker.html) and never forget to accept right answers :)

Comment: That i have already tried and got error:

Assertion failure in -[ZBarReaderViewController setSourceType:],
/Users/spadix/zbar/hg/sdk/iphone/ZBarReaderViewController.m:650

Answer (score 0):

if you are geting problem in ZBar.

Then you can use ZXindWidget for scaning.

here is link you may refer for this

[Link](http://yannickloriot.com/2011/04/how-to-install-zxing-in-xcode-4/comment-page-2/#comment-1063)

Comment: It is also giving same problem.